# How to create a tanglegram in R that connects two dendrograms cut through a given number of clusters?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend

I have two dendrograms resulting from hierarchical clustering and I want to visually compare them using a tanglegram. However, I only want to display a certain number of clusters that are cut at a predefined level. How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: Hey. The tangegram can be done using tangegram (from dendextend). You can also prune your dendrograms using the prune function. The issue is to discover which labels to keep. For that you'll need to do some manipulation using cut and labels. I suggest you give a specific example if you want more help.

Comment: @TalGalili, yes, please provide the example.

Comment: Ivan - I'm asking YOU to give an example for me to work on :)